# How to draw triangle using linux kernel and hardware acceleration?

Tags: linux, opengl

I have x64 cpu, rx480 ATI graphics card and running linux kernel with some glibc and busybox. It boots to command line.

Next thing i want to do is to switch monitor to 1920x1080 exclusive mode and start drawing a rotating triangle. This is **only** task i want to perform, hence i need:

- avoid using X, creating windows and messing with all that stuff
- make use of hardware acceleration, to top up FPS

I got really confused with complexity of the stack and enormous number of existing terms (technologies, libraries) like EGL, OpenGL ES, DRI, DirectFB, XOrg... What do i need to draw a triangle, while keeping call stack short?

Comment: Your most likely options are to 1) program with svgalib and use VESA video modes for drawing. You won't have hardware acceleration, but will be able to keep the dependencies short; 2) use OpenGL over X11 and get hardware acceleration. For a single triangle case, your FPS will be limited by your monitor hardware, not by the software stack.

Comment: @FBergo Hmm.. i dont like both. GLX is the option i try to avoid and svgalib.. hey its 2018's!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried [kmscube](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/kmscube) ([kernel modesetting (KMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager#Kernel_mode_setting) + [generic buffer management (GBM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesa_(computer_graphics)#Generic_Buffer_Management) + [EGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EGL_(API))) on Debian Buster with an R9 Fury running the open-source drivers and it happily put up a cube onto [virtual terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) 1, even while Xorg was running.

Comment: Feels like a good starting point to start learning things up. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, is it hardware accelerated? You haven't mentioned amdgpu-pro driver. What is it for? Do i need to extract some shared library from amdgpu-pro to get stuff working? Where do so-called acceleration "lives"?

Comment: @xakepp35: Yeah, pretty sure it's hardware-accelerated, though I haven't hacked in any debug output to dump `GL_VENDOR`/`GL_RENDERER` to check.  No `amdgpu-pro` (AMD's closed-source driver), just the open-source [`amdgpu`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMDGPU) driver.